# Monthly report by time

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

[image][image]I work in a parking company. We need a report of monthly vehicle exits by time.

```
select hour(datetimeout) as 'dateout',count(*) 
from to_leaveveh 
where datetimeout between '2014-09-01' and '2014-09-02' 
group by dateout
```

This only shows data for one day. I want to create a monthly report with:

1. Time in 24 hour format
2. Count of vehicle exits

Comment: Can you add some sample output, how it will look like

Answer (score 2):

Use the [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datetimeout,'%H:00:00') ExitHour,count(*) VehicleExitCount
FROM to_leaveveh
WHERE datetimeout >= ('2014-09-01' + INTERVAL 0 SECOND)
AND   datetimeout <= ('2014-09-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH - INTERVAL 1 SECOND)
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(datetimeout,'%H:00:00');
```

or

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datetimeout,'%H:00:00') ExitHour,count(*) VehicleExitCount
FROM to_leaveveh
WHERE datetimeout >= ('2014-09-01' + INTERVAL 0 SECOND)
AND   datetimeout <  ('2014-09-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH + INTERVAL 0 SECOND)
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(datetimeout,'%H:00:00');
```

Give it a Try !!!

## UPDATE 2014-09-22 08:26 EDT

The queries I gave break down each by our hour of the month. You get no more than 24 rows.

If you want group by date and hour, then try this

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datetimeout,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') ExitHour,count(*) VehicleExitCount
FROM to_leaveveh
WHERE datetimeout >= ('2014-09-01' + INTERVAL 0 SECOND)
AND   datetimeout <= ('2014-09-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH - INTERVAL 1 SECOND)
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(datetimeout,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00');
```

or

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datetimeout,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') ExitHour,count(*) VehicleExitCount
FROM to_leaveveh
WHERE datetimeout >= ('2014-09-01' + INTERVAL 0 SECOND)
AND   datetimeout <  ('2014-09-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH + INTERVAL 0 SECOND)
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(datetimeout,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00');
```

Give it a Try !!!

## UPDATE 2014-09-22 15:07 EDT

This will group by date and hour with a summary by date and an overall summary

```
SELECT
    IF(
        ISNULL(dt)+ISNULL(hr)=2,'Monthly Total',
        IF(ISNULL(hr)=1,CONCAT('Total for ',dt),HOUR(hr))
    ) Statistic,VehicleExitCount
FROM
(
    SELECT
        DATE(datetimeout) dt,
        DATE_FORMAT(datetimeout,'%Y-%m-%d') hr,
        COUNT(*) VehicleExitCount
    FROM to_leaveveh
    GROUP BY dt,hr
    WITH ROLLUP
) A;
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Not working above query.

Comment: Sorry, I had `WHERE` twice. I replaced the second `WHERE` with the word `AND`. Give it a Try !!!

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA, shouldn't that be `<` instead of `<=` and `+ 0` seconds, i.e.: `AND   datetimeout < '2014-09-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH + INTERVAL 0 SECOND`  ?

Comment: @ypercube you're right. I tweeked it. Thanks for looking over my shoulder :-)

Comment: Thanks it is working, but i want to day shows in column format which is show above picture.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA,thanks for giving solution.Please help on create monthly report inwhich ROW show only date field and column show date(1-30). Report sample excel copy attached above. Kindly give me solution for the same.

Comment: Sir, above query is running but not fullfil my requirement. it is showing output Statistic VehicleExitCount
0 1294
Total for 2014-06-23 1294
0 1373
Total for 2014-06-24 1373
0 1425
Total for 2014-06-25 1425
0 1508
Total for 2014-06-26 1508
0 1659
Total for 2014-06-27 1659
0 1289
Total for 2014-06-28 1289
0 1401
Total for 2014-06-29 1401
0 1453
Total for 2014-06-30 1453
But we want to create report in other form which is mention excel image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select hour(datetimeout) as 'dateout',count(*) 
from to_leaveveh 
where datetimeout between '2014-09-01' and '2014-09-02' 
group by hour(datetimeout);
```

Comment: Sir, it showing datepart is not register function. i want to create report inwhich row showed Time in 24format and column showed 1st to 30th all vehicle out data.

Comment: DATEPART is not register function as showing query error message output.

Comment: @vijayp the OP is getting notifications when you edit your answer, no need to ping him with comments.